# Laravel Snappy PDF Exit Status Code 127

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I am trying to print a HTML to PDF file for hardcopy and file purposes of my project in Laravel. I tried to use the [barryvdh/laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) so I followed the documentations carefully and I also installed [this wkhtmltopdf for ubuntu 16.04 64x bit](https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/bd89079245923c04be6b0f92af431c10) cause I think it is required in order to use this package. But there is a big problem. When I generate a PDF sample using Snappy it gives me this error.

[image]

Is there something wrong in the installation of my wkhtmltopdf? or is it a directory issue? I tried to **sudo chmod -R 777 usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf** but still got the same error.

I also followed this [this link](https://laravelcode.com/post/html-to-pdf-in-laravel-using-barryvdh-laravel-snappy) to help me out. But ended up in the same error.

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Btw I am using Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit

wkhtmltodf version - 0.12.3.2

Comment: So where's your executable? Try `which wkhtmltopdf`. Code 127 means there's no such command. As you can see the script is trying to run `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`. And why did you install it globally? There's amazing, statically linked [wkhtmltopdf binary](https://packagist.org/packages/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64) available to install with Composer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the below package for integrating PDF feature.
I personally use this and its working great and easy to use.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

If you came across any issue using this plugin please ask me i will help you out for sure.

E.g
Make sure to install and configure this package as mention in the document also make sure to run the below command after installation and configuration of this package.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"
```

then try using the below code:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('j F, Y');
data = ['date'=>$date];
$pdf =  PDF::loadView('admin.pages.application', $data)->setPaper('a4');

return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
```

Comment: can I also return this as a view first in PDF format in my browser before I download it? this is DomPDF right?

Comment: yes its' dompdf. you can return view too using this code : return view ('admin.pages.application')->with($data); OR  return $pdf->stream('download.pdf');

Comment: I am using this package but Bootstrap and my custom css files are not working.

Answer (score 0):

on my Ubuntu 20.04 i had to install a few more dependencies for it to work

Edit this file /etc/apt/sources.list and add this line to the end of it: `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main`

After that run: `sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev`

Finally: `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`

And finish with: `sudo apt-get install libxrender1`

Answer (score -1):

Please give 777 permission to vendor folder and then check it